# App:environment is returning a blank page on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables

I want to check what environment the application is in, and then declare a specific binary config.

The file is located within the /config/ folder.

At the moment, this is what I have:

```
<?php

if (App::environment('local')) {

    return array(

    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => base_path('vendor/profburial/wkhtmltopdf-binaries-osx/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64-osx'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),

} else {
    // The environment is production
}

);
```

But it's returning an error (blank page).

How can I inherit the `App` class to use it?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get when you do `dd(App::environment())`? And what environment is setup in you `config/app.php` & `.env` file?

Comment: When I `dd(App::environment());` it returns a blank page, and this error in my PHP log - PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App' not found in /Users/ben/Documents/audit/config/snappy.php on line 3. The environment set up in `config/app.php` is  `'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production')`. In my .ENV file is - `APP_ENV=local`.

Comment: Have you perhaps changed your Application name? Try `\App::environment()`

Comment: My app name is default, as set by Laravel. If I try the above I get the same error.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this check in a config file? If you use `dd(App::environment())` in your `routes.php` file, it should work fine. Your config files aren't supposed for this.

Comment: Because I have to declare what binary file I'm using in my /config/ directory. I completely understand where you're coming from, but I don't think I have a choice.

Comment: Posted final answer. That should work. Hope it helps!

Comment: Just check for the env variable.. like this: `if (env('APP_ENV') == 'local')`

Comment: Ahh looks like it's been answered already,

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if (env('APP_ENV') == 'local')
{
    return array (
        'pdf' => array(
            'enabled' => true,
            'binary' => base_path('vendor/profburial/wkhtmltopdf-binaries-osx/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64-osx'),
            'timeout' => false,
            'options' => array(),
            'env'     => array(),
        ) 
    );
} else {
   // Not local environment...
}
```